# how to build url with a form

Tags: php, html, post

The site will be using php & mysql

For my new site i'm trying to have clean url and instead of having the horrible 
page?x=1&y=23&ee=23 I would like to have something nicer.

Using a form with a POST method, I would like to get something like

http://www.xxx.com/page-color-blue-size-12-light

If action="action-page.php" then the page loaded will then need to read the $_POST from action-page.php and create a new URL and redirect to the new URL and this does not seem to be a great idea.

If I use $_GET, I will then endup with url with ? and & as parameters.

Could the solution be a JS that update the method before clicking on submit but in this case the site will not work for google...

As you can see I can't find a good solution... any idea?

Note -

Thanks for the reply, but I'm not looking for URL rewriting, that would be the case If I was trying to read  http://www.xxx.com/page-color-blue-size-12-light  but it's not what I'm trying to do, i'm trying build this URL from a post.

Answer (score 1):

Send paramenters via POST request

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The request URL will be just `page.php`, and `$_POST['data']` will contain your parameter.

If you want to use URLs like `http://www.xxx.com/page-color-blue-size-12-light`, then you need

- redirecting by Web-server by some rewrite rule;
- routing to other page by parsing the URL in PHP-script.

May be the first solution is better because the second one means processing of 2 HTTP-requests.

Comment: Agreed, but I would like the url to be not page.php but page-color-blue-size-12-light I could build this from a $_POST

Comment: Why would you ever want to name your file like that? The name shouldn't determine how the URL looks like.

Comment: I don't want to name any file, I'm just trying to build an URL that will then be interpreted by my code, it could be by using rewriting or  parsing the URL.

Comment: by the way look the url of the question, that might help to understand why it's good to name url like that.

Comment: @zavg that's my issue, I'm trying to avoid redirection and double parsing, the only solution seems to be using java script, but this will not work for bots...

Comment: @Arnaud not JavaScript, but web-server rewrite rules

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing but called as URL rewriting. You can find more info on this from the following website.

http://www.cyberdesignz.com/blog/website-design/url-rewriting-top-5-ways-of-php-url-rewriting/

Comment: URL rewrites would be if I wanted to be able to transform page-color-blue-size-12-light into page=blue; size=12 ; value=light, I'm tring to build a nice url from a $_POST

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking for help doing [URL rewrites](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/). They cover the basics of having your location bar show something pretty instead of all the query string parameters you mentioned.
Update:

I understand your question a little better and I think I may have a solution that will at least get you the first part of your question.  I put this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66cGv/) for you to check out as well.

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="blue"/>
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="size" name="size" value="12-light"/>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#myform").submit(function() {
        var color = $("#color").val();
        var size = $("#size").val();
        $("#myform").attr("action", "/page-color-" + color + "-size-" + size);
        $("#myform").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: URL rewrites would be if I wanted to be able to transform page-color-blue-size-12-light into page=blue; size=12 ; value=light, I'm tring to  build a nice url from a $_POST

Comment: So you want the form submission to generate a new page for you? That would still require some URL Rewriting to handle on your server, but you could use some javascript to build out the form url. Let me edit my answer with an example.

Comment: This looks perfect, I will also need to write a version for bots (goole and others) because I don't think they enable javascript while parsing sites...